# Выбор по css селектору BeautifullSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть некая страница. В ней есть элемент, текст которого я хочу распарсить.
Консоль Google Chrome позволяет скопировать селектор для конкретного элемента. Как зная селектор получить элемент использую bs4? С классами все понятно. Однако если в селекторе используется тэги или ид, то не очень понятно как их использовать. 
Если мне надо получить элемент класса `myclass` то я пишу:

```
`r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
soup.find('span',{'class':'myclass'})
```

Вопрос: Могу ли я использовать css селектор типа `span.myclass` или это надо писать отдельными конструкциями. Возможно есть какая-то другая библиотека для парсинга html страниц. Буду благодарен за любую информацию. Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: вы можете дать ссылку на страницу где это можно было бы протестировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для css-селекторов используйте метод [select](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
soup.select('span.myclass')
```